# How to print barcode in Centos 6 using python

Tags: python-2.7, centos6, zebra-printers, barcode-printing

I want to print Barcode on my Zebra Desktop label printer on CentOS 6.5 but I did not find any python drivers for that and did not found script so that i can use in my project.

Does anyone know how to print Barcode in Zebra printer?

Answer (score 2):

If you are printing to a network printer open a TCP connection to port 9100. If you are printing to a USB printer look up a USB library for python.

Once you have a connection send a print string formatted in ZPL. Look on the Zebra site for the ZPL manual. There are examples in there on how to print a barcode.

Normal Linux drivers will print graphics and text but do not have a barcode font.

Comment: what actually talks to that 9100? I know of their 'browser print' rest server that uses that port, but I see references in Zebra blogs that seem to be sending raw data to port 9100 and at least some of the threads talk about doing it on USB connected printers (without built-in network support). But we can't seem to get any of those methods to work.